# Django translation not working for DE language

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext

I created translations .po and .mo files for language de and en.

When I lunch my code with German settings, with

```
print(translation.get_language())
>> de
```

it print right language, but translations doesn't work (I get english translation)

I have:

```
# Translations
# Provide a lists of languages which your site supports.
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
)
# Set the default language for your site.
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
# Tell Django where the project's translation files should be.
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

In HTML

```
{% load i18n %}
<label class="bmd-label-static" for="date">{% trans 'Date' %}</label>
```

in django.po

```
msgid "Date"
msgstr "Datum"
```

My files are arrange like:

```
locale
  |
   -> de
      |
       -> LC_MESSAGES
              |
               -> django.mo
               -> django.po
   -> en
      |
       -> LC_MESSAGES
              |
               -> django.mo
               -> django.po
```

Comment: What are your browsers language settings?

Comment: I have German language in browser... inside view.py when I open first page, I print the language print(translation.get_language()) and it prints de

Comment: Does your middleware settings include `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware`? Is `USE_I18N` set to `True` in settings?

Comment: Thank you. It was the USE_I18N=True....